# Calculate average excluding current observation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, excel-2010, average

How do I calculate a mean (or any other summary statistic) excluding
 the *current* observation?

> For example, I have following data:

i   `-`   value   `-`   category

1   `-`  5  `-`          1

2   `-`  5  `-`          1

3   `-`  9       `-`   1

4    `-`  2     `-`      2

5   `-`   2     `-`      2

> I would like to calculate the mean for each category (egen value_mean
>   = mean(value), by(category)), but exclude the i-th observation:
>   For i=1, for example, the mean value by category 1 would be (5+9)/2.
>   For i=3, it would be (5+5)/2. For i=4, it would be 2/1.

There were various threads online matching my question, the closest one being [this one](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-05/msg01201.html), but I do not understand the explanation and I'd require something in Excel, not whatever language that is.

My range for data is an entire column, formula so far works and looks like this:

`=AVERAGEIFS(A:A,D:D,D3,E:E,E3,AP:AP,AP3)`

But as you can see it does not exclude the current observation, namely the value in A3.

There ought to be a simple solution, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you could switch to `SUMPRODUCT` so as to be able to create an explicit reference to the row in which the formula resides (not possible within `SUMIF`), I'd probably prefer the slightly longer:

`=(SUMIFS(A:A,D:D,D3,E:E,E3,AP:AP,AP3)-A3)/(COUNTIFS(D:D,D3,E:E,E3,AP:AP,AP3)-1)`

which retains the advantage that these functions have over `SUMPRODUCT`, in that arbitrarily large ranges can be referenced with no detriment to performance.

Regards

Comment: The approach seems sound, but the values I get from using your formula are massive and I'm not sure why. They come out about 8000x larger than my averageif result

Comment: I take it you placed the formula I gave in row 3?

Comment: Oops solved it, I was using a named range instead of A:A and forgot to replace it in yours. Thank you so much, it works as expected

Comment: Hi @DavidAndreiNed, if this answered your question please "Accept" the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Yup I'm aware, was considering whether to expand my question further, but I can pretty much figure it all out on my own from there, thanks again